# Examples of functions that are not Borel measurable that will be accessible to 1st year undergraduates

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, education, borel-sets

While teaching statistics, I've grown sick of using terms such as "under (very) weak regulatory conditions..." and would like to be able to provide some solid examples of when these conditions are not met. For example, it's well known to any stats student that for a continuous random variable X and for a "sufficiently nice" function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we have E[$g$(X)]=$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x) \ \mathrm{dx}$. However, any stats student who knows their measure theory will know that, in this case, "sufficiently nice" means 'Borel Measurable'.

This leads me to the gist of my question. Are there any examples of non-Borel measurable functions that are simple enough to be explainable to someone who may have only just learned (or may not even know) set theory but are general enough to stress that the condition of 'g must be Borel measurable' is so weak that they won't really need to worry about it?

Comment: I disagree that this something one need not worry about.

Comment: This does not seem like a real problem.  "Under very weak [regularity] conditions..." implies, more or less, that any example a student will ever see satisfies those conditions.  Unless they are graduate students in a stats program (and not maybe not even if it is an applied stats program), I can't imagine this being an issue.

Comment: That being said, the simplest construction of a nonmeasurable set is Vitali's construction, which appeals to the Axiom of Choice.  That, already, seems like a little to much for a first year undergraduate, who likely has not yet had any courses on set theory or basic mathematical logic.

Comment: @XanderHenderson What 1st year undergrad hasn't done set theory? In my country, it's the first thing that they get taught.

Comment: @J.Mini Almost no first year undergrad in the United States will have taken course in set theory.  The typical undergraduate mathematics curriculum in the US consists of a year of single variable calculus, followed by a year of multivariable calculus, linear algebra, and/or differential equations.  Students often take their first course in mathematical logic at the beginning of their third year.  These classes needn't focus on set theory, and often take other approaches (e.g. "discrete math" classes, which focus on properties of the integers; or courses in formal logic).

Comment: Moreover, most stats students in the US will never hear the phrase "Borel measurable" (statistics is generally considered an applied program at US institutions, and is often even housed in its own department, disjoint from mathematics).  Someone with a bachelors degree in statistics may never have heard of a Borel set, let alone a first year undergraduate (indeed, many *mathematics* students won't see the term, as measure theory is typically taught as a graduate class at US institutions).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ah, in which case you've both revealed a flaw in my question and broken my heart. Well done. That being said, even in my country, most students won't hear the term until they do a course in one of Lebesgue Integration (final year undergrad), Stochastic Processes (also final year) or some serious mathematical finance (graduate level). Come to think of it, how can you possibly teach an undergraduate course in mathematical finance without these ideas?

Comment: I have this conjecture: If a function is practical for real life then it is measurable. (so 'sufficiently nice' means 'not a made up theoretical non measurable function')